# Почему производный класс не может обращаться к конструктору с параметрами базового класса?

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, наследование, конструктор

Почему производный класс в С++ (ООП) не может обращаться к конструктору с параметрами базового класса?

> Важной особенностью производного класса, является то, что хоть он и может использовать все методы и элементы полей protected и public базового класса, но он не может обратиться к конструктору с параметрами. Если конструкторы в производном классе не определены, при создании объекта сработает конструктор без аргументов базового класса. А если нам надо сразу при создании объекта производного класса внести данные, то для него необходимо определить свои конструкторы.

Почему?

Comment: Видимо этот конструктор помечен как `private` или вызывается не для инициализации базового подобъекта производного объекта.

Comment: нет, дело не в модификаторе. а вообще  в принципе. ЦИТАТА "Важной особенностью производного класса, является то, что хоть он и может использовать все методы и элементы полей protected и public базового класса, но он не может обратиться к конструктору с параметрами. Если конструкторы в производном классе не определены, при создании объекта сработает конструктор без аргументов базового класса. А если нам надо сразу при создании объекта производного класса внести данные, то для него необходимо определить свои конструкторы."

Comment: Ааа, добавьте эту цитату прямо в вопрос.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как я понял, тут речь идет о том, что при наличии в базовом классе конструктора с параметрами, при конструировании объекта дочернего класса просто так вызвать его нельзя:

```
class foo
{
    public: foo(int, int, int) {}
};

class bar: public foo
{};

int main()
{
    bar b(1, 2, 3); // ошибка
    return(0);
}
```

Раньше пришлось бы писать конструктор `bar` класса:

```
class bar: public foo
{
    public: bar(int x, int y, int z): foo(x, y, z) {}
};

int main()
{
    bar b(1, 2, 3); // Ok
    return(0);
}
```

Но с приходом С++11 вместо этого можно унаследовать конструкторы базового класса:

```
class bar: public foo
{
    public: using foo::foo;
};

int main()
{
    bar b{1, 2, 3}; // Ok
    return(0);
}
```